# How to assign count to a document in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where each document has a word and they are unique throughout the collection. As per my requirement, I executed a script such that whenever I insert a word (document) which already exists, it doesn't get inserted.

Now, in such cases I need to add count to the word whenever I try to insert a same word. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very elegantly by combining [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) with [upsert:true](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter).

When you perform an update with the `upsert:true` option and no document matches your update criteria, the document is inserted into the collection.

When you use `$inc` and the specified field doesn't exist in the updated document, it gets created and is sets to the value you increment by.

So when you perform:

```
db.collection.update(
    { word:"Banana" },
    { $inc: { count: 1 } }, 
    { upsert:true }
);
```

two cases are possible.

- When a document like `{ word: "Banana", count: 42 }` exists, it gets changed to `{ word: "Banana", count: 43 }`.
- When no document with `word: "Banana"` exists, a document `{ word: "Banana", count: 1 }` is added to the collection.

By the way: When you have performance problems, you should be able to speed this up by creating an unique index on `word`. Considering that you have a single field which is never an array and which you always query by exact equality, you can use a [hashed index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/) which is amazingly fast with larger collections.

Comment: I understood your answer, but this is how my document looks like for a word say"cancer".                                                                                                {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5538643c49aa20a608ee2b7c"
    },
    "0": "c",
    "1": "a",
    "2": "n",
    "3": "c",
    "4": "e",
    "5": "r"
}

Comment: @Vamshi I am horrified by whatever wicked mind devised this dreadful schema. A part of me is curious about what insane train of thought could have lead to this, but the saner part of me is too afraid of the answer... Whatever. What I described should still work when you break up the word like this and query for the index of the next letter with `{ $exists: false }` to avoid matching longer words which begin with the new word. Execpt for the hashed index, of course.

Comment: Haha yeah i understand.. but i get the data from a different source only in this way. Anyway i got the way to deal with this data. Thank you.

Comment: @Vamshi When I was able to answer your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon next to it.